# java.lang.stackoverflowerror on jsf application with tomcat

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, stack-overflow

Hi i am trying to figure out stackoverflow error.

All i know is the error comes from

> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.setAttribute on line
>   278

But I have no idea whats causing it.

What is the best way to trace the error? This is like finding a needle in a hay stack since there are over 50 classes.

How do I know which method is calling this to get an error? (like which method do I want to turn debug mode on to trace this stackoverflow).

Comment: Please share the stacktrace anyway. The repeating patterns can tell something about the cause.

Comment: java.lang.StackOverflowError is usually caused by an infinite recursive call.  Do you have access to the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to nail down the real cause without seeing the stacktrace and interpreting/understanding the repeating patterns.

However, the most common beginner's mistakes which can cause a `StackOverflowError` in a JSF webapplication are the following:

- An invalid `FacesServlet` mapping. E.g. mapped on `*.jsp` while views are by itself already `*.jsp`. You should map it on something else, e.g. `*.jsf`. This is not necessary when you're using JSF2 with Facelets. Both the views and mapping can be `*.xhtml`.
- A JSF view file with an invalid file extension. E.g. *actually* having a `page.jsf` file instead of a `page.jsp` or `page.xhtml` while the `FacesServlet` is mapped on `*.jsf`.

I dare to bet that yours is caused by either of those causes. Other possible causes usually boils down to own bad code in backing bean classes, but it would usually not have involved container's internal classes such as `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher` in the repeating part of the trace.

Comment: You're betting? How much are you willing to put in the table? :p

Comment: @The Elite: hm, drinking a jug of beer with you over there in South Africa, including an air ticket.

Answer (score 1):

best way to trace the error is to look at the stack trace, there is probably something recursive going on, your trace will probably have repeating sequences of method calls.

Answer (score 0):

In `TOMCAT_HOME/logs/` folder (Tomcat 6 & 7), there's a `catalina.yyyy-mm-dd.log` file that contains all the logged messages (including exceptions thrown by the application). Get the latest (today's) log file and see where the exception was thrown (usually the most recent time the error occurred).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and for me it seemed to have been a bug - Creating an empty faces-config.xml made it go away (was the workaround). CDI was also configured/installed.